# ¿Cómo crear un campo calculado en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Soy nuevo en MySQL y tenía la duda en como hacer esta base de datos con un campo calculado en una base de datos en MySQL , como verán en la imagen solo lo logré hacerlo en SQL Server pero en MySQL ya cambia y no se como hacerlo.

```
Create Database BDVENTAS
GO
USE BDVENTAS
GO

create table Productos(
ID_Producto Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Producto varchar(20),
precio_unidad decimal(6,2),
cantidad_producto integer,
total_productos as precio_unidad * cantidad_producto 
);
```

Comment: Por favor, coloca el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: @jachguate listo

Comment: Con MySQL >=5.7: `total_productos decimal(65,2) as (precio_unidad*cantidad_producto)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis para crear una columna calculada en mysql es:

```
NombreCampo TipoDato as (formula)
```

Por tanto, podrías intentar con algo como:

```
create table Productos(
ID_Producto Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Producto varchar(20),
precio_unidad decimal(6,2),
cantidad_producto integer,
total_productos decimal(10,2) as (precio_unidad * cantidad_producto) 
);
```

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando un gestor del tipo PHPMyadmin, puedes usar el constructor y en el apartado de virtualidad escoge virtual y coloca ahí tu fórmula.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos!

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida y solucionada en el 2021. Te recomiendo que leas [answer]

Comment: Gracias por la retroalimentación, por supuesto noté la fecha de la pregunta. Sin embargo, es importante recordar que también es un repositorio de soluciones y quizá a alguien le pueda servir la solución alterna.

"Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones "

Answer (score -1):

```
create table Productos(
ID_Producto Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Producto varchar(20),
precio_unidad decimal(6,2),
cantidad_producto integer,
precio_unidad * cantidad_producto as total_productos
);
```

Primero intenta realizar la operación y a ese resultado le asignas un alias, no al contrario.